# Swift - Use button to manually scroll UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, uitextview

I want to use a button to scroll **down** or **up** in `UITextView`,
but I ran into a problem.

Using `textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: MyTextView.contentOffset.y + 100), animated: true)` can make my textview scroll down, but it still scrolls  when I click the button in the end of text...

like this..

```
e
f
g




===================
```

But I want is this..

```
a
b
c
d
e 
f 
g
===================
```

My code is

```
@IBAction func down(_ sender: UIButton) {
   MyTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: MyTextView.contentOffset.y - 100), animated: true)
}

@IBAction func up(_ sender: UIButton) {
   MyTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: MyTextView.contentOffset.y - 100), animated: true)
}
```

please help me!!!

Comment: please, add a code snippet of the button action.

Comment: setContentOffset needs a cgpoint as an argument but you are only giving it a cgfloat .  contentOffset.y + 100 gives cgfloat , not cgpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
@IBAction func down(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (textView.contentSize.height>(textView.frame.size.height+textView.contentOffset.y+100)){

        textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:textView.contentOffset.y + 100), animated: true);
    }
    else{
        textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:(textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height)), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: but when I change to 10 to 100 still scrolls out of boundary

Comment:   Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

## I have tested and it works. Check this out

```
 @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func up(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if textView.contentOffset.y < 100{
            textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
        }else{
            textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: textView.contentOffset.y-100), animated: true)
        }
    }
  
    @IBAction func down(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if textView.contentOffset.y >  textView.contentSize.width - textView.frame.size.height{
            textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: textView.contentSize.height-textView.frame.size.height), animated: true)
        }else{
            textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: textView.contentOffset.y+100), animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check what the current offset is and only move the amount you need to. For example for scrolling down, try something like below. Then you should be able to adjust it and do the opposite for scrolling up.

```
struct Constants {
    static let preferredScrollAmount: CGFloat = 100.0
}

@IBAction func downButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Get the current offset, content height, text view height and work out the scrollable distance for the text view
    let currentOffset: CGFloat = textView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight: CGFloat = textView.contentSize.height
    let textViewHeight: CGFloat = textView.frame.size.height
    let scrollableDistance = contentHeight - textViewHeight

    // Check that the current offset isn't beyond the scrollable area otherwise return (no need to scroll)
    guard currentOffset < scrollableDistance else { return }

    // Work out how far we can move
    let distanceWeCanMove = scrollableDistance - currentOffset

    // Get the distance we should move (the smaller value so it doesn't go past the end)
    let distanceToScroll = min(distanceWeCanMove, Constants.preferredScrollAmount)

    // Do the scrolling
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentOffset + distanceToScroll), animated: true)
}
```